# There's a 0 adding to the value on multiple post type

Tags: php

I was wondering where did the "0" came from here:
[image]

I have a query with multiple post type but when I tried to echo the value from those post types it adds '0' to the value. how will I fix this here's my code:

```
   $args = array(
    'post_type' =>array('complan_a','complan_b','complan_c'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'orderby'   => array(
          'date' =>'DESC',
          'menu_order'=>'ASC',
          /*Other params*/
         ),
    'post_status' => array('publish','future'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'title' =>  $username
   

);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

     $payin_id   = get_the_ID();
     $complan_a = get_field('complan_amount',$payin_id);
     $complan_b = get_field('complan_b_amount',$payin_id);
     $complan_c = get_field('complan_c_amount',$payin_id);

     $profit = get_field('amount_profit',$payin_id);
     $profit1 = get_field('complan_b_profit',$payin_id);
     $profit2 = get_field('complan_c_profit',$payin_id);
  ?>  


<td>
    <?php echo $complan_a;?>
        <?php echo $complan_b;?>
        <?php echo $complan_c;?>
</td>
<td>
        <?php echo $profit;?>
        <?php echo $profit1;?>
         <?php echo $profit2;?>
</td>
```

Comment: this is being added to the `complan_c_profit` field? Is that an ACF field? You might need to ask this question somewhere else if you're having issues with ACF or another custom fields/metabox plugin, 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here

Comment: hello, the value on acf field on the CPT doesnt contains 0 it probably on the way it echo. because when I tried to only show one field its working fine

Comment: can you expand your code? What I'm seeing in the screenshot can't be generated by what I read in the code, there's a lot of markup and other parts missing. e.g. where is the table markup coming from? And there are no separators between `$profit`, `$profit1` and `$profit2`. Also how did you test that the ACF field does not contain `0`? How do you know multiple post meta entries aren't present and some of those have `0`? If your code inside a function we can't see? Note that if this requires understanding or knowledge of ACF in any form then the question is offtopic and not allowed here

Comment: hello I tried to use a single post type and echo  `$profit`  it doesnt shows the zero, but when I tried to add another post type and echo `$profit2` the `0` is showing, I think its based on the array of the post type. As I notice that when the value of the 3rd post type is being echoed there's a two `0` showing on the start.

Comment: I updated the code above

Comment: Why is it called profit if the column is labelled asteroids?From what I can see you're outputting 3 variables, and in the screenshot each row has 3 numbers, e.g. 0,0,700. So `amount_profit` and `complan_b_profit` have the value `0` and `complan_c_profit` had the value `700`. What are you actually trying to display in that column? And you've still shared no information about the fields

Comment: what i suspect is that you've created a field for each post type, and you're trying to display them, expecting that `complan_c_profit` will only display for the posts of type `complan_c`, and you've set these up as number fields. However it's returning `0` because there is no number and you've misunderstood how the fields in ACF work. If you want to display a single number not 3, then you need to `echo` once, not three times. Perhaps the solution is basic addition `+`

Comment: But I need to show the value of those complan `a` to `c` or is there a way to echo those 3 field once? Also I just wanted to show the value of the `profit` without a 0

Comment: but if you display all 3 values you will get 3 numbers, and if one of those values is `0` then you will get a `0`. I don't think you've described your goals very well, That column has 3 values, can you describe your goal a different way? "echo those 3 field once" doesn't make sense in english in this context. Do you want to display the total value? Or are you saying only one of those fields has a non-zero value? Or are you asking where the `0` comes from? You can only ask a single question so be very clear and specific, I can't write an answer if I don't know what's meant to go in that column

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.